# What is the meaning of the phrase "acting reel"?

Tags: meaning

I can not understand the meaning of phrase ***acting reel***. I hear it several times. As far as I understand in one case it means to act in a movie, but I am not sure.

So, what is the meaning of the phrase ***acting reel***?

Comment: Do you have some context to give us?

Comment: Only the last one. I web page of a model which section is called `acting reel`. I try translation and there are a lot of menanigs for word `reel`. I think the answer of @Josh61 is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An acting reel is most often called a show/demo reel:

> - A ***[showreel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Showreel_(actors)) (also known as a demo reel)***  is a short piece of video or film footage showcasing an actor or presenter's previous work. Usually 2 to 3 minutes in length, a showreel typically supplements an artist's résumé and is used to promote the artist's skill, talent, and experience to acting agents and casting directors.

Wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

A **[reel](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:+reel)** is a device used to store film.

> a cylinder on which film, wire, thread, or other flexible materials can be wound.

[image: film reel]

So an **acting reel** refers to the film that holds scenes that the actor has acted in. But more generally it refers to an actor's past roles, not the literal film that recorded those roles.